# white space in cell array

Tags: matlab, whitespace, cell

I am using textscan to read text file and I get <55x1 cell> 
examples:

```
 'aa a aa'
 'a  aaaa a'
 'a =  aaaaa'
 'aaaaaa'
 ' a a a aaa'
 'aa'
 'aaa'
 'aaaa'
  .
  . 
  .
  .
```

I want to delete the white spaces in each sting
If I have a sting

```
 string = 'I am 24 Years    old'
```

And I use

```
  string(ismember(string,' ')) = [];
```

it will eliminate the spaces and I will get

```
 'Iam24Yearsold'
```

But with the cell doesn't work or I don't know how to do it
How can I do that? any suggestions please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html):

```
a = { 'aa a aa'
 'a  aaaa a'
 'a =  aaaaa'
 'aaaaaa'
 ' a a a aaa'
 'aa'
 'aaa'
 'aaaa'
 'I am 24 Years    old'};

strrep(a, ' ', '')
```

This results in

```
ans = 

    'aaaaa'
    'aaaaaa'
    'a=aaaaa'
    'aaaaaa'
    'aaaaaa'
    'aa'
    'aaa'
    'aaaa'
    'Iam24Yearsold'
```

Comment: this only catches a space, not other whitespace -- if anyone cares